# How to use html, css, jss and assets in react native webview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I want to use html, js, css and assets in my react native webview. I tried a lot but only things worked for me is passing html as string source.

But I want to import files and use them in react native webview. Also not getting much useful help in google.

Is it possible to use them by importing or any workaround for it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this for a while and while there might be sth you can do for the JS stuff using [injectedJavaScript](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript) I can't think of anything for HTML and CSS.

When I was using Electron with react, what I used to do was to write my react code and then use ReactDOMServer's renderToString ([description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring)) to parse my react code with all its resources back to a string which I then injected into the page (images and other assets loaded fine).

I'm just not sure if you CAN use ReactDOMServer in React Native.